# NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

Tags: python

Работаю на W7 64 SP1.

Написал программу, которая должна печатать заданные пользователем штрихкоды на принтере этикеток.

Использую модули в *Python 3* для связи с принтером.

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
import libusb
```

(1.0)

Через `Zadig` установил драйвера `libusb-win32 (v1.2.6.0)`.
В диспетчере задач отображается деление *libusb-win32 devices*, где отображается принтер *USB receipt printer*.(пробовал устанавливать и другие драйвера *libusbK USB devices* и т.д.)

Из папки  *libusb-1.0.20\MS64\dll* скопировал файл *libusb-1.0.dll* в *C:\Windows\System32*.
Также из *libusb-1.0.20\MS64\dl* скопировал файл *libusb-1.0.lib*  в *C:\Program Files\Python38* и *C:\Program Files\Python38\libs*.

Часть кода, которая отвечает за печать

```
def pech():
    p = Usb(0x8086, 0x1c2c, 0, profile="default")
    for b in a.split():
        p.barcode(b, 'CODE128', 10, 30, align_ct=True, function_type=None, check=True)
        p.cut()
    print(p)
```

Во время запуска печати через программу получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/LOL/Desktop/papka/Metod 2.py", line 68, in pech
    p = Usb(0x8086, 0x1c2c, 0, profile="default")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.open(usb_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 88, in open
    self.device.set_configuration()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 915, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 158, in managed_set_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и как мне победить эту ошибку.
Через `Zadig` пробовал устанавливать другие драйвера - ошибка такая же.

Comment: попробуйте запустить в Linux